# Create and download a tar archive in the browser client-side without using server

Tags: javascript, browser, web-applications, download, tar

I want to create a multiple csv files and download it as **tar** archive in the browser without sending request to the server using javascript.

I found library  [JSZip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip), which does everything what I want but creates a zip archive. I have a specific requirement to create a tar archive.

Let me know if any other way to create a tar archive on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution using Tarts: [github](https://github.com/porsager/tarts) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tarts)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tarts@1.0.0/dist/tarts.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const tar = Tar([{
            name: 'index.html',
            content: '<!doctype html><h1>Hello world</h1>'
        }]);


        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([tar], { type: 'application/tar' }));
        a.download = 'filename.tar';
        a.click();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any other approach or package available? As tarts library seems not maintained regularly and very few users are using it.